# How to use Record separator of AWK command in linux

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file named marks.txt which has marks of students as shown below

```
Jones
2143
78
84
77

Gondrol
2321
56
58
45

RinRao
2122
38
37
65

Edwin
2537
78
67
45

Dayan
2415
30
47
20
```

Here, each student is separated by two newlines and for a particular student his marks are separated by a single newline.
Now, I want to print these details in a tabular format using below command

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n", FS="\n";} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' marks.txt
```

But it is showing syntax error.

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
```

Someone, please help me with this problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual syntax error. Saying `it is showing syntax error` is like just telling your mechanic `my car isn't working` instead of describing  the actual symptoms to them so they can try to fix it. By the way `RS="\n\n"` isn't going to cause a syntax error but won't work as you want in most awks, you should be using `RS=""` instead for portability, and you don't need to do `print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5`, just `$1=$1; print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses `,` to separate two instructions. You need `;` instead:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"; FS="\n";} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file
Jones 2143 78 84 77
Gondrol 2321 56 58 45
RinRao 2122 38 37 65
Edwin 2537 78 67 45
Dayan 2415 30 47 20
```

Comment: Thanks, @terdon, it is working.